# Angular: Nested http call with ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

In angular, I want to convert this nested HTTP calls in ngrx pattern. But how can I do it? I thought to create one action related to getUser and one to `getPost`. But I can't understand how can I pass the getUser response as a parameter to `getPost` function...

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get('localhost:8080/api/user').subscribe(user => {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'userId': user.id
    });

    this.http.get('localhost:8080/api/posts', {
      headers
    }).subscribe(posts =>
      this.posts = posts;
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: You are looking for https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap

Answer (score 0):

There are various higher order operators you can use including `concatMap`, `switchMap`, `exhaustMap` and `mergeMap`, e.g we can transform your above code to below

```js
ngOnInit() {  
  this.http.get('localhost:8080/api/user').pipe(
    mergeMap(({id: userId}) => {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'userId' : user.id
      });
      return this.http.get('localhost:8080/api/posts', {headers})
    })
  ).subscribe(post => this.posts = post)
}
```

If you have control over the backend, I would also propose changing your api to `posts/:id` rather than as a header, something like below

```js
ngOnInit() {  
  this.http.get('localhost:8080/api/user').pipe(
    mergeMap(({id: userId}) => this.http.get(`localhost:8080/api/posts/${userId}`)
  ).subscribe(post => this.posts = post)
}
```

Finally also consider using `async` pipes. this will enable automatic subscription and unsubscription. Also your code will be easier to maintain

In your TS file

```js
user$ = this.http.get('localhost:8080/api/user');
posts$ = this.user$.pipe(
  mergeMap(({id: userId}) => this.http.get(`localhost:8080/api/posts/${userId}`)
)
```

and your html

```html
<div *ngFor='let post of posts$ | async'>
  <!-- post variable available here -->
</div>
```

Comment: This is clear...but with ngrx haven't I use actions, reducers and effects?

Comment: In this example you may not necessarily need to use `ngrx` but if you can implement it that would be great